# Either 2 newlines or 0 FileOutputStream

Tags: java

My grandpa got a new pixel 2. There is a little glitch with Google Assistant where it can't text numbers formatted a certain way in the contacts CSV even though they are validly formatted. IPhone used (xxx) xxx-xxxx format where as Google just uses xxxxxxxxxx . Anyway I thought I would be ambitious and make a little quick fix script since I'm learning java. CSV files use Cp1252 charset and the newline byes are 0D, 0A. I've tried adding them in several different ways. My problem is my FOS either doesn't add new lines when it appends the file, or if I manually add in a new line it then adds another new line on top of the one I add manually. Some of the oddities in my code such as converting to hex were a result of me manically trying everything to get it to only add one line. I checked the hex without my addition of newline characters and the result is no newlines `00 00 00`, when I add newlines each lines ends with hex `00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A` *2 newlines, I really have no clue why*
 **Code of file write class below:**

```
package reformat;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class WriteFile {

private final File file;

WriteFile(String fName){
    System.setProperty("line.separator", "\u0000");
    file = new File(fName);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeF(String line){
    //fix new line pattern for csv
    byte[] lineStream = line.getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp1252"));
    lineStream = Arrays.copyOf(lineStream, lineStream.length +1);
    line = new String(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(lineStream));
    line = new String(line.substring(0, line.length()-4));
    line = new String(line + "000D000A");
    //System.out.println(line);
    lineStream = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(line);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        fos.write(lineStream);
        fos.close();
        //System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use streams to read and write text. Use a Reader and a Writer. Google for Java IO tutorial.

Comment: Okay... but why not? I could have used a reader and writer I did this because it was initially more expedient looking and I would like to know why it is behaving the way it is, not "Just do it a completely different way because *shrugs*". Reading the file using Streams and lamda expressions felt sigggnificannnntlllly cleaner than using a reader.

Comment: why not? Because `writer.print("hello\r\n")` is much clearer, simpler, readable, maintainable and much less error-prone than writing `stream.write(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("68656C6C6F0D0A"))`

Comment: Your code proves it, BTW. To write \r\n, two characters encoded to two bytes in Cp1252, you're using the hex string "000D000A", which contains 4 bytes. Why are you reading and writing text using hex? Why not read it as text?

Comment: Ehhhh. Okay. I'll do the writer thing. It's just more of an OCD thing. I really wanted to know WHY it's broken more than how to fix it. Oh the whole reason I converted it to hex is that it was misbehaving in the same fashion when using plane characters. After I figured out that no new line characters were being added by comparing the hex of my generated file to the original, I initially tried adding "\r\n" to the end of a the string to be written, which had the same effect of adding the equivalent of "\r\n\r\n". So long story short I tried a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Well, `NUL` bytes are certainly not a good idea to put into your text file.

Comment: The format of this particular file has a null byte between each byte.

Comment: You said the encoding was cp1252. That encoding does not have nul bytes between each byte. If it did, it wouldn't be cp1252 but ucs-2 or utf-16.

Comment: By the way, in the discussion with JB Nizet above, you seem to be talking on different wavelengths. JB is talking about java.io streams, while you appear to be talking about Java 8's java.util.stream streams.

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest that you show us the original code that you used before you started using hex. It will probably be simpler and allows to see where the problem is. The simple fact is FileOutputStream does not duplicate its newlines, so there must be something you're doing wrong. But it's hard for us to see because you've complicated things by converting to/from hex.